pytube oauth/po token bypass or automation
Im trying to make a program that has a part where it downloads an audio stream of a Youtube video using pytube (or pytubefix). The problem however is that it now requires either oauth or PO token which the pytubefix itself gets only via its own prompt, but I am planning on sharing my programm so I can't do that. Is there any way of generating a PO token and inserting it directly in the pytube.YouTube() or automating oauth or not using it at all?
I already tried searching for scripts that generate tokens, and I sorta found one, but it is unstable and I still don't know how to put the token without prompting pytube to.

pytubefix, worked for me without oauth. you can also pass in the following: allow_oauth_cache=True, use_oauth=True, token_file='path to token.json'

@CYW as I said, I'm planning on publishing the program and I don't think that a single token works forever
